# How to pass a ViewBag/ViewData from a PartialView to the parent view in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, viewdata

I need to get the value of my `ViewData["CurrnetPageId"]` which is inside an action method returning a partial view, in its parent view.

My parent action method called `ShowSingleProduct` looks like this:

```
[Route("/Single/{id}")]
public IActionResult ShowSingleProduct(int id)
{
    var product = _productService.GetProductById(id);

    if (product.DiscountId != null)
    {
        ViewData["PriceWithDiscount"] = _discountService.GetPriceAfterDiscount(product.Price, product.Discount.PercentValue);
    }
    else
    {
        ViewData["PriceWithDiscount"] = 0;
    }

    return View(product);
}
```

And there is a child action called `_ShowComments` which returns `PartialView()`:

```
public IActionResult _ShowComments(int id, int take = 2, int pageId = 1)
{
    ViewData["CurrnetPageId"]= pageId;
    var comments = _productService.GetAllCommentsByProductId(id, take, pageId);
    return PartialView(comments);
}
```

When I need to have the value of `ViewData["CurrnetPageId"]= pageId;` in the child view, at the parent view, setting `null` as a value to `ViewData["CurrnetPageId"]= pageId;`!!

I tried it by using jQuery/ajax as shown below (this is within the parent view `ShowSingleProduct.cshtml`):

```
@{
    var currentPage = ViewData["CurrnetPageId"];
}
.
.
<div class="text-center">
    <button onclick="showMoreComments(@currentPage)" class="btn btn-outline-accent" type="button"><i class="ci-reload me-2"></i> See More.. </button>
</div>
.
.
function showMoreComments(id) {
     $.ajax({
                url: "/Products/_ShowComments",
                type: "get",
                dataType: "html",
                data: { id:@Model.ProductId, pageId: id }
            }).done(function (res) {
                $(".product-review").html(res);
      });
<script>

</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi @Hossein, ajax cannot refresh the page by default, what your did here `$(".product-review").html(res);` is just update this element's(class="product-review") value. From your view, it seems you want to get the viewdata here:`showMoreComments(@currentPage)`,right?

Comment: @Rena Yes I do. you know, I need to show more comments by every clicking on a button named `See More`, So I need to plus the ViewData by 1 after avery click in order to be able show more comments using some procces

Comment: So, you mean each time you click the button, the pageId should be increased 1, right? If so, suggest you use client side way to store the pageid. I will show you a sample.

Comment: @thanks, That would be great if you can explain that why the ViewData return `null` in this case? ;(

Comment: Hi @Hossein, ViewData only works when page rendering. For the first time your parent view render, it does not have any value. When you click the button, although it set the value, But as what I said before, ajax will not update the whole page and you only update the element `class="product-review"` here. So only the element in this element will update. Other element will keep the value before.

Comment: @Rena Thanks a lot Rena, So I'm waiting for your sample :)

Comment: OK. Just for confirmation. Did you only have one button? And the pageId will plus 1 each time you click it?

Comment: @Rena Yes, I have one button and I plus 1 by pageId each time

Comment: Hi @Hossein, pls check my answer. Any problems you can follow up to let me know.

Comment: `dataType: "html"`?? didn't you mean `dataType: "application/json",` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewData only works when page rendering. For the first time your parent view render, it does not have any value. When you click the button, although it set the value, but as what I said before, ajax will not update the whole page by default and you use `$(".product-review").html(res)` update the data in the element `class="product-review"` here. So only the code in this element will be updated. Other element will keep the value before.

I suggest you using `localStorage` to store the client side data.

Here is a simple demo you could follow:

View:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button onclick="showMoreComments()" class="btn btn-outline-accent" type="button"><i class="ci-reload me-2"></i> See More.. </button>
</div>

<div class="product-review">

</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        localStorage.setItem("pageId",1);
        function showMoreComments() {
            var id =parseInt(localStorage.getItem("pageId"));
            $.ajax({
                    url: "/Products/_ShowComments",
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: { id:@Model.ProductId, pageId: id }
                }).done(function (res) {
                    id=id+1;
                    localStorage.setItem("pageId",id);
                    console.log(localStorage.getItem("pageId"));
                    $(".product-review").html(res);
               
            });
        }
</script>

}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult _ShowComments(int id, int take = 2, int pageId = 1)
{
    //ViewData["CurrnetPageId"] = pageId;
    var comments = _productService.GetAllCommentsByProductId(id, take, pageId);
    return PartialView(comments);

}
```

Comment: But you've changed the value of `id`, which is my `@ModelProductId`, into `1`!! You must rename the var `id` on the top of `$.ajax({ ...`, for example, I named it `idd`! :) . then modify all of id's aftar that and rename them to `add` so that it could work correctly. And Thank u very much for helping.

Comment: And also I Changed 1 into 2 in this part: `localStorage.setItem("pageId",1)`;. So it bcame as this: `localStorage.setItem("pageId",2)`;

Comment: `But you've changed the value of id, which is my @ModelProductId, into 1` Just change to `@Model.ProductId`. I just used `1` for easy testing .

Comment: `var id on the top of $.ajax({ ..., for example, I named it idd! :` be sure your function here `function showMoreComments(id)` does not have id.

Comment: Yes, but I got a little confused for the time being, after taking a look at the codes again, I got it !:) Thank u so much.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it, thanks again.